# How do I return a HashMap populated with multiple rows using mybatis?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have an INSTR_ROUTING database table with three columns:
[image: INSTR_ROUTING table]

My Java code is:

```
    public Map<String, String> getInstrumentRouting() {
    return getSqlSession().selectMap(NAMESPACE_PFX + "getInstrumentRouting", "INSTR_INSTANCE_NM");
```

and mybatis I've tried multiple ways, the latest two are:

```
    <select id="getInstrumentRouting" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
    select  INSTR_ROUTING_ID    as irId,
            INSTR_INSTANCE_NM   as instrumentName,      
            LAB_SYSTEM_NM       as destinationName  
    from INSTR_ROUTING
    WHERE INSTR_ROUTING_ID = #{irId, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

and:

```
    <resultMap id="instrumentRoutingMap" type="com.labcorp.adapter.di.common.InstrumentRoute">
    <result column="INSTR_INSTANCE_NM" property="instrumentName"
        jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="LAB_SYSTEM_NM" property="queueInstanceName"
        jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getInstrumentRouting" resultMap="instrumentRoutingMap">
    select  INSTR_ROUTING_ID    as irId,
            INSTR_INSTANCE_NM   as instrumentName,      
            LAB_SYSTEM_NM       as destinationName  
    from INSTR_ROUTING
    WHERE INSTR_ROUTING_ID = #{irId, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

All I've been able to get is an empty Map "{}" or an exception, e.g. saying it can't find the type "java.util.HashMap".

Can anyone set me straight? This should be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a simplified version working. I changed it to only get the one LAB_SYSTEM_NM for a given INSTR_INSTANCE_NM (instead of loading the entire table).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<select id="getDiInstanceName" resultType="String">
    select LAB_SYSTEM_NM as destinationName 
    from INSTR_ROUTING
    WHERE INSTR_INSTANCE_NM = #{instrumentName, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

```
    public String getDiInstanceNameFor(String instrumentName) {
    return getSqlSession().selectOne(NAMESPACE_PFX + "getDiInstanceName", instrumentName);
}
```

Hope that helps someone else.